Reserving a resource (room) with Google calendar API
I am using the Google calendar API (direct html, not a library) to create meetings. When one of the attendees is a resource, I use the appropriate email address for the resource, and set the "resource" property to true. When looking at the event after it gets added, the resource is there as an attendee, the room icon and name is set, so it looks correct. However when I view the calendar for that resource, the event is not there.  The resource calendar does show other events that were created manually.  Below is an example of the input json.  Any ideas what the problem is?
{
 "summary": "Test API event",
 "extendedProperties": { "private": { "JeffCreated": "yes" } },
 "description": "",
 "location": "Seattle Main Conference Room",
 "iCalUID": "3e8584bde19045e84bc245e81492e9c5-28159",
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2024-05-01T08:30:00-07:00",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
},
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2024-05-01T09:00:00-07:00",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York"
},
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": false,
  "overrides": [
  {
  "method": "popup",
  "minutes": 15
   } ]
 },
 "attendees": [
  {
  "email": "jsnuffy@testdomain.com",
 "resource": false,
 "optional": false,
  "responseStatus": "needsAction"
  },
  {
  "email": "Jason@testdomain.com",
 "resource": false,
 "optional": true,
  "responseStatus": "needsAction"
  },
  {
  "email": "tmglgapps.com_3435383633373331313633@resource.calendar.google.com",
 "resource": true,
 "optional": false,
  "responseStatus": "accepted"
  },
 ],
 "visibility": "default"
}



Hi! Can you please confirm what you mean about direct HTML, are you referring to calling a function using your HTML file? Or otherwise please share more information about it so we can replicate it.  Also I am having trouble understanding your main question, are you having issues creating the event or not seeing the result of your actions through the API from which perspective. What are the things you have tried so the community can have better oversight about what is happening.

I have a C++ program using libcurl that does a POST to the url "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars//events/import".  The supplied JSON is shown above.  The post is successful and the event does get created in the user's calendar.  It's just that I expected having a resource (room) in the attendee list would automatically create an entry in the calendar for that resource, but it does not.

Can you try to remove these two options? "optional": false,
"responseStatus": "accepted" on the part of resources check if that works for you. As I was able to do it removing those two. Please let me know if how it works out.

Removing those options did not make a difference for me.  What does make a difference, which I tried on a hunch because Microsoft 365 does the same thing, is to add to the URL "sendNotifications=true". I don't mind the resource getting the notification, but I don't want to do it for normal attendees. I'm wondering if I could make two calls, one to send out the notification to the resource, then a second to update the meeting with the normal attendees?  If you have any suggestions, please let me know, thanks.

I do apologize for this it seems that the request body you are trying to add is already deprecated it shouldn't work so can you share the calendar settings of your resource along with code of your project where you do this call where it works?

I did notice that I should use "SendUpdates=all" instead of sendNotifications - is that what you're referring to?  But anyway the procedure I mentioned above seems to work. I create the event, sending a notification to the resource.  Then PATCH the newly created event with the remaining attendees, sending no notifications.  Other than making two calls instead of one, I don't see any downside.

I can see no downside with this as well. If this fits your expected result. I would suggest just keeping it at it is.
